# How to confirm for unlocking by `adb backup/restore` on Bluestacks?

Tags: android-emulator

i use Bluestacks(for Hyper-V) 4.180.0.4205.
and try to restore apps on the Bluestacks.

1. settings > preferences > ADB enabled
2. restart Bluestacks
3. adb command for restore:

```
$ adb -s emulator-5554 restore <package name>

Now unlock your device and confirm the restore operation.
```

but Bluestacks does't display dialog for confirm.
how to confirm?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the android settings app on bluestacks hyper-v 4.280.0.4206 and then issue the adb restore command. The dialog will pop up